# Requestmapping a controller to another controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UpdatePassword", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myUpdate()
```

That I want that to then go to my other controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getIndex(){}
```

And update the clients url to `www.myApp.com/`, ie not `/UpdatePassword`.

What do I need to put in my updatepassword controller method ? We have a view resolver and an interceptor that add's .jsp, or mobile+viewname+.jsp to our view names, we want to keep this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `"redirect:"` prefix in the response of the /UpdatePassword URI.

Comment: We have a view resolver and an interceptor that add's .jsp, or mobile+viewname+.jsp to our view names, this fails

Comment: This should not be a problem, as the redirect should throw a 30x HTTP status code that is managed by the browser and not by the Spring MVC infrastructure.